# SCOM 2007 - SQL Server Monitoring

Tags: sql-server, scom

I've been tasked with comparing the monitoring capabilities in SCOM 2007 with the established SQL products such as Spotlight, SQLSentry, etc.
   I'm pretty sure that SCOM can't do some of the more in-depth stuff that those products do, but can it be configured/programmed to alert on the most often encountered problems via VBScript and TSQL. Does anyone have an idea of what type of development effort would be needed for this? Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

In the [guide for the SCOM SQL management pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=8C0F970E-C653-4C15-9E51-6A6CADFCA363&displaylang=en) you can download a complete detailing of exactly what the management pack offers.  As far as monitoring goes (IMHO) I'd take SCOM over spotlight every day of the week.  Where Spotlight shines is in performance analysis and maintenance data (EG spotlight can tell you what the top SQL query is SCOM is designed to alert you when any one runs too long).  If you really wanted to you caould create your own management pack or script that outputs what SCOM can monitor.  As far as effort it's not that bad.  Scripts are the easiest as they will simply output to a log or (my preference) the windows event log.  Management packs are not difficult to author.  See [this blogpost](http://blogs.technet.com/b/apage/archive/2010/03/30/creating-a-scom-management-pack-for-your-application.aspx) for a sample experience